# Calculate accuracy from Keras model.predict_generator

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification

I have Keras model and I want to evaluate it using my test data.
When I use keras `model.evaluate_generator` I get loss and acc returned by it and I can print the percentage accuracy like:

```python
loss, acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_gen, steps=evaluation_steps)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], acc * 100))
```

This results in something like 92%.
As I wanted to create a confusion matrix (too see how much false positives and false negatives I have) I changed my code to:

```python
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=evaluation_steps)
y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
y_true = np.argmax(labels, axis=1)
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

I get correct confusion matrix with this. However, I still want that 92% displayed, can I get it from `predictions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accuracy can be calculated in a straightforward way from your `y_pred` and `y_true`; here is an example with dummy data for 3-class classification:

```python
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1])
y_pred = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2])
```

Simple visual inspection here tells us that our accuracy should be 0.5 (50%); so:

```python
l = len(y_true)
acc = sum([y_pred[i]==y_true[i] for i in range(l)])/l
acc
# 0.5
```